# Absolute phrase without a participle? Or something else?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, syntactic-analysis

I'm trying to learn how to break apart sentences and understand each part's name and what exactly it does (excuse my ignorance; I've read quite a bit, but I'm still new at it). I came across the following construction and, simple as it seems, I can't figure out what it's called. I thought it might be considered an absolute phrase, but those are usually defined as having a participle. So what would the second half of these sentences be considered and what is their function? Am I way off base? Are these even grammatical? Thanks!

> Hens are stuffed into tiny cages, **unable to lift their wings.**
>
> He moved unsteadily, **clumsy enough to fall at any moment.**

Comment: Yes, they are grammatical. At the simplest, the parts share a common phrase. "*Hens are* stuffed into tiny cages. (Therefore,/ So badly that) *Hens are* unable to lift their wings."

Comment: Those aren't absolute clauses, because they modify something, namely *hens* and *he*, respectively. An absolutely clauses does not modify a specific phrase, but rather the entire sentence or nothing.

Comment: They are parenthetical, but they aren't *absolute* because the phrase lacks a subject.  They fall under the *[reduced] free modifier* category, which lacks subject and tense -- the verb is a participle, but since it is copular ("[being] clumsy") the participle is omitted (reduced).

Answer (score 2):

These are *dependent clauses*, which are being used as *modifiers* applied to the subject of each sentence. They function in the way an adjective functions; they describe nouns.

They don't need a participle to be grammatical. They are grammatical except that in the first sentence the clause is awkwardly placed, creating what is often called a *misplaced modifier* (also called a *dangling modifier* and other names as well). The reason it is misplaced it that it seems to modify or describe the *cages*, rather than the *hens* (that is, it seems to be saying that *the cages* are unable to lift their wings). There are many ways to fix this. One possibility would be this: "The hens are unable to lift their wings once they are stuffed into the tiny cages."

Comment: +1 and so a dependent clause is by definition not an absolute clause.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute phrases don't always have to contain a participle.

[Check this explanation out.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/phrases.htm#absolute)

In your example, the participle "being" is omitted, as it usually is in absolute phrases.

Answer (score 0):

These are not clauses, nor are they absolute phrases — they are adjectival phrases.